# Difference in graph plotted from excel and python?

Tags: python, pandas

Loaded the text file using pandas, and plotted the graph for selected two columns (mentioned in `pd.read_csv` command line)

Text files are [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnYf-TOGUWKSjJwyrPhFETdZN04UCQ).

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

files=sorted(glob.glob(r"adress of folder containing text files\*.txt")) 
T_raise= pd.read_csv(files[1],delimiter=',',skiprows=1,index_col=False,usecols= 
["COLUMN A","COLUMN B"])
t=T_raise.iloc[1:6900,0]
T=T_raise.iloc[1:6900,1]
plt.plot(t.values,T.values)
```

Plot obtained from python and excel are different, Python showing linear one which is not correct (Please find png of graph plotted from excel in link )

Comment: Did you try to create a temporary data frame, with a group by, and after tried to regenerate a graph plotted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above problem of slowing down is sorted out, by using 
a  buffer csv file

```
zip(t,T)
    with open('text.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerows(zip(t,T))
```

to fetch the values for graph,

```
# lines can be used for reading the different text files with similar number of columns, and getting graphs for selected columns and plotting them together in one figure 
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import glob
i=0;
files= sorted (glob.glob('<address of the text files there in link shared in question above\*.txt')) 
nof = len(files)
for i in range(0,nof):
    T_raise= pd.read_csv(files[i],delimiter=',',skiprows=1,index_col=False,usecols=["column A","Column B"], header=0)

    t=T_raise.iloc[1:len(T_raise)-1,0]
    T=T_raise.iloc[1:len(T_raise)-1,1]
    zip(t,T)
    with open('text.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerows(zip(t,T))
        T2_raise=pd.read_csv('text.csv',delimiter='\t',header=0)
        t2=T2_raise.iloc[1:len(T2_raise)-1,0]
        T2=T2_raise.iloc[1:len(T2_raise)-1,1]
        plt.plot(t2,T2)
```

Suggest if any better ways to do it, thanks